# C# project configuration and environment variable

Tags: asp.net-core, configuration

I am using dot net core application. 
I need to use the same source for development, staging and production. 
So I want to control all these environment with the project configurations.

I tried config transformations as mentioned in the below link,
https://dzone.com/articles/config-transformations-in-aspnet-core-1

In local, Made changes in launchsettings.json/ added new profile.
Based on the environment variable (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT), appsettings files are loaded.

while publishing source to Azure environment, I dont have option to choose environment variable. Is if possible to map these environment variable in project configurations (like 
1. 'Release' configuration mapped to environment 'Production',
2. 'Debug' configuration mapped to environment 'Development')

Is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

That article is not necessarily wrong, but confusing as all get out.

First, these are not "transforms". Nothing is transformed. In old ASP.NET, the Web.config was literally changed as part of the publishing process. Nothing of the sort happens with ASP.NET Core. In other words, the standard "Release" and "Debug" configurations in Visual Studio have no effect whatsoever on your ASP.NET Core app. You could publish either way, and you end up with the same exact publish result.

Instead, an ASP.NET Core is essentially published with all environments. The decision about which environment to run as is made a runtime, either based on the value set for the environment variable, `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` or based on command-line argument.

To set environment variables for an app hosted in Azure, you simply set the appropriate setting for you app in the Azure portal. Azure app settings are added as environment variables. In other words, go to the settings for your app in Azure and add one called `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with the value of the environment you want to run under. Then, you're good to go.

Also, launchSettings.json is only for IIS Express in Visual Studio. It does nothing and has no purpose outside of that.

Comment: LaunchSettings.json can contain multiple settings for launching the web server and the browser directly from Visual Studio. In addition to IISExpress, it also contains settings for IIS and the built-in .NET Core web server.